# python regexp matching one or more characters in a group, except for particular alternatives

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to match all combinations of `<>=/*+-` except for `=` and `=>`. How can I do this?

```
 r = re.compile(r'[<>=/*+-]+')
```

This matches one or more characters in the set but I don't know how to prevent it from matching the `=` or `=>` patterns. I'd guess it has something to do with negative lookahead or lookbehind but it's hard for me to wrap my head around that.

---

*clarification*: I literally want to match all combinations of the characters in `<>=/*+-` except for `=` and `=>`. In other words, I want to find maximal-length consecutive substrings consisting only of these characters -- and if the substring equals `=` or `=>`, it should not be considered a match.

I apologize for not clarifying earlier, but it seemed like a simple enough problem statement not to need the extra clarification.

Example cases:

- `pow pow -> bah bah` contains the match `->`
- `a +++->* b // c` contains the matches `+++->*` and `//`
- `=> 3 <= 4 = 5 == 6` contains the matches `<=` and `==` (remember, `=` and `=>` are not matches)
- `a <=> b <@> c` contains the matches `<=>` and `<` and `>`
- `---= =---` contains the matches `---=` and `=---`

Comment: To clarify, `=<` should match but `=` and `=>` should not? Also, this looks as if you're matching operators like `+` and `+=`, but as written strings like `/*>=` will match. Is that what you want?

Comment: So if there's a `=>`, do you want to find the `>`, or nothing?

Comment: Also, following up on what @JohnKugelman says: regexps are a bad way to parse expression syntax, but there are very good ways to do it that are simple and efficient; you can build an [OP parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser) or other simple shift-reduce parser from scratch pretty easily, or use something like PyParsing.

Comment: I want arbitrary strings of those characters except for `=` or `=>`. So `==` or `/**+` or `-=>` should match, but not `=` or `=>`.

Comment: FWIW I'm working on a lexer using ply (which uses regexps). There's a higher-level question here but I want the answer to this one first so I can form my other question more intelligently.

Comment: @JasonS: So `=>` should not match as `>`, but `==>` should match as a single group?

Comment: abarnert: "So if there's a =>, do you want to find the >, or nothing?" I want to find nothing.

Comment: @JasonS: And the other question? In `a==>b`, you want the `==>`?

Comment: If you insist on going the re route, I think that it might be best to split this into two expressions - one matches the characters you do want, and then one filtering out the characters you don't want. There probably is a single expression that will do it all, but it will probably be quite unreadable.

Comment: @nfazzio: And it may also be horribly inefficient (possibly even requiring exponential backtracking, while two linear regexps in series is obviously still linear—and they're dead-simple and fast ones, too).

Comment: @abarnert: You seem to know way more about regex than me - do you know of any tools that compute the time complexity of pattern matching?

Comment: @nfazzio: IIRC, someone proved (with Perl regexps, which are not quite the same as Python's, but pretty close) that it is impossible to determine which regexps can be exponential in sub-exponential time. You could easily write a tool that flagged any regexp that _might_ be exponential, but that would give you a ton of false positives. See [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) for a simple discussion, and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887724/why-can-regular-expressions-have-an-exponential-running-time) for lots of good links.

Comment: @JasonS: Since there are a lot of non-obvious edge cases here, instead of answering them one by one in comments and leaving us to try to guess the consequences, it would really help to provide a list of test cases and expected output to make this unambiguous. The question really should be meaningful to someone who hasn't read dozens of scattered comments, and this one is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edited: Implemented abarnert's suggestions below:

I would split this into two parts:

The first part will return a list of all matches - including the '=>' and '=' that you don't wish to match.

```
p1 = re.compile(r'[<>=/*+-]+')
```

The second part will filter these matches out.

```
all_matches = p1.finditer(your_string)
matches = [match.group() for match in all_matches if match.group() not in ('=', '=>')]
```

Comment: Great approach, and nice simple implementation. But two minor quibbles. First, if you've got a compiled regexp, use `p1.findall(s)`, not `re.findall(p1, s)`. Second, use `finditer` instead of `findall`; no reason to build a list just to iterate over it.

Comment: @abarnert: thanks for the suggestions - I've implemented them. A question about the `callable-iterator` type: If I iterate through it once in a list comprehension, how can I iterate through it again? If I do the list comprehension twice, the first time it results in what I want, but the second time it results in an empty list.

Comment: You can't iterate through an iterator twice. After you create `matches`, `all_matches` is empty. If you really _need_ to iterate through something twice, then you probably want a list. But in most cases, you don't have any need for that, so don't pay the cost. See [Iterators](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) and the following sections in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
pat = re.compile(r'((?!=|=>)[<>=/*+-]+)')
```

It uses negative look-around syntax, described in detail here:
[Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

**EDIT:** The simple look-around above will unfortunately match ">" when fed "=>" so to work around that it can get a little hairy:

```
pat = re.compile(r'((?!=>|(?!=)>)([<>/*+-]|[<>=/*+-]{2,10}))')
```

I'm assuming you don't want to match strings longer than 10.  This separates the matches into single-character operators (from which we exclude "=") and multi-character operators (where "=" is ok) except for "=>" -- It also excludes an edge case we're not interested in, just the ">" of the rejected "=>"

This is completely unreadable, however, and if it makes it into your code there should be copious comments.  Agree with other commenters that a single regex is not suited for this problem.

Comment: Just saying that something "might work", especially without any explanation, doesn't really help as an answer.

Comment: @TomMcClure: I changed `re` to `pat` so as not to shadow the `re` module.

Comment: Also, this doesn't work `print re.search(pat,'<=>').group()` matches `'<=>'`.

Comment: according the to the OP, he's fine with <=>

Comment: But this does the wrong thing for any case that's a valid match, but starts with `=` or `=>`—for example, `==>` will match `>` instead of `==>`.

Comment: OK, when I run your more complicated one on `a<=>b` it finds `<` multiple times, and never finds `<=>`. So this still isn't what he asked for.