# Regex taking too much time

Tags: python, regex, performance

I created 2 regex (re1 and re2), if I try to compile the first regex (re1) it takes about 30 seconds to find all matches.
and if I try to compile the second regex (re2) it takes about 1 second to find all matches.

Can you help me find the difference or what causing this problem?
Thanks!

```
import re
data = b'000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
re1 = b'.*00.*00.*00.*00.*76.*62.*55.*75.*'
re2 = b'.*aa.*00.*00.*6f.*63.*20.*6d.*75.*'
reg = re.compile(b'^%s$' % re1, re.RegexFlag.M)
results = len(reg.findall(data))
print(results)
```

Comment: I think it is because using `.*` it will first match until the end of the line and then backtracks trying to match the rest of the pattern. When there is no match, there are a lot of `00` to backtrack to and it explores all the paths when there is no match.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/340590), and really you want something like a [bitmask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31576303/4541045) to find bits set in known positions

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from **backtracking** in the implementation of CPython regexp engine (as emphasized by @Thefourthbird). It comes more specifically from the first and the last `.*` which are not needed **if data do not contain new line characters**. Indeed, in this case, `findall` will either find only one match (all data due to the `.*`) or nothing. So you do not need `findall`: a `search` is enough. Moreover, using `^` and `$` with `.*` prefixed and suffixed is not useful too. The following code should produce the same effect but is 20 times faster on my machine (still not very fast regarding the input size).

```py
import re
data = b'000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
re1 = b'00.*00.*00.*00.*76.*62.*55.*75'
re2 = b'aa.*00.*00.*6f.*63.*20.*6d.*75'
reg = re.compile(re1, re.RegexFlag.M)
results = 1 if reg.search(data) else 0
print(results)
```

**If data contain new line characters**, then it is a bit more complex as only the line containing the pattern will be matched. Indeed, *`.` does not match a new line character* (since `RegexFlag.DOTALL` is not present). One solution to overcome the problem consists in splitting lines before and then apply the regexp. Another solution consists in using the above code, then replacing the `search` line with a `finditer` to track the location of the matches, then track the beginning and the end of the lines of each match.

If you want to know more about why backtracking causes such a slow execution you can look at this post: [Why can regular expressions have an exponential running time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887724/why-can-regular-expressions-have-an-exponential-running-time).

Note that `re1` is a quite critical regexp for this data. There are much faster regexp engine to compute it. The *Google's RE2* regexp engine is a **linear-time regexp engine** that should be much faster in such critical cases (but generally not so on non-critical data). There is also the *Intel's Hyperscan* regexp engine which is generally very fast compared to other engines (although a bit less user-friendly).