# PySpark drop columns based on column names / String condition

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to drop columns in a pyspark dataframe that contains any of the words in the `banned_columns` list and form a new dataframe out of the remaining columns

```
banned_columns = ["basket","cricket","ball"]
drop_these = [columns_to_drop for columns_to_drop in df.columns if columns_to_drop in banned_columns]

df_new = df.drop(*drop_these)
```

The idea of `banned_columns` is to drop any columns that start with `basket` and `cricket`, and columns that contain the word `ball` anywhere in their name.

The above is what I did so far, but it does not work (as in the new dataframe still contains those columns names)

Example of dataframe

```
 sports1basketjump | sports
```

In the above column name example, it will drop the column `sports1basketjump` because it contains the word basket.

Moreover, is using the `filter` or/and `reduce` functions adds optimization than creating list and for loops?

Comment: df.drop(drop_these,axis=1)

Comment: @Wen Hi Wen ! I do not think that axis exists in pyspark ? or ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your list comprehension does not do what you expect it to do. It will return an empty list, unless it *exactly* matches a string. For an answer on how to match a list of substrings with a list of strings check out [matching list of substrings to a list of strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234965/matching-list-of-substrings-to-a-list-of-strings-in-python)

The `df.drop(*cols)` will work as you expect.

Comment: Since this answer was helpful to some, I would rather link the question.

Comment: good point, feel free to tweak the question a little bit :) so the answer is more relevent

Comment: will do, can you please link your new q/a so I can link it?

Comment: here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51322445/how-to-drop-all-columns-with-null-values-in-a-pyspark-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Assuming dataframe `df` that needs to have some columns dropped, first build a regular expression that will match the banned columns substrings. That can be done by basically combining the string values with `|`. The resulting value for pattern is `"basket|cricket|ball"`.

```
import re
banned_columns = ["basket","cricket","ball"]
pattern = "|".join(re.escape(s) for s in banned_columns)
```

Now build the regular expression and store it in a variable for use in the filter.

```
crexp = re.compile(pattern)
```

The complete list of column names `df.columns` is filtered with the `filter` command. The result of the filter command is an enumerator so use `list` to enumerate it into the desired list of column names.

```
drop_these = list(filter(lambda s: (crexp.search(s)), df.columns))
```

Finally, drop the unwanted columns.

```
df_new = df.drop(*drop_these)
```