# How to handle AttributeError in python?

Tags: python, regex

I am working through some example code which I've found on [What's the most efficient way to find one of several substrings in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842856/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-find-one-of-several-substrings-in-python). I've changed the code to:

```
import re
to_find = re.compile("hello|there")
search_str = "blah fish cat dog haha"
match_obj = to_find.search(search_str)
#the_index = match_obj.start()  
which_word_matched = ""
which_word_matched = match_obj.group()
```

Since there is now no match , I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

What is the standard way in python to handle the scenario of no match, so as to avoid the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `match_obj` is `None` because the regular expression did not match. Test for it explicitly:

```
which_word_matched = match_obj.group() if match_obj else ''
```

Comment: Much appreciated - Bill

Comment: This is an interesting way to phrase it. I haven't seen this before.

Answer (score 4):

```
match_obj = to_find.search(search_str)
if match_obj:
    #do things with match_obj
```

Other handling will go in an `else` block if you need to do something even when there's no match.