# Find index of first matching substring

Tags: python, string

I want to search through a string and get the first index of any sub-string in a given set of sub-strings.

I tried `'word'.find('g' or 'r')` and expected this to return the index: 2, but `or` does not work obviously.

How can I achieve this concisely?

Comment: use regex `'g|r'` but with module `re` instead of command `find`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the most efficient way to find one of several substrings in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842856/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-find-one-of-several-substrings-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use re module here:

```
import re

re.search(r'[gr]', text).start()
```

In case you have separate substrings:

```
re.search(r'(foo)|(bar)', text).start()
```